# Javascript. Why does not work this code?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

## I can not call the property height:

When I call the height property, the message get 0. But it should give me 1152.

```
var fondoJuego=new FondoJuego();
fondoJuego.setFondoSrc("tituloNV.png");
alert("Altura "+fondoJuego.getFondo().height);

var FondoJuego=function(){
            this.fondo=new Image();
            this.getFondo=function(){
                return this.fondo;
            };
            this.getFondoSrc=function(){
                return this.fondo.src;
            };
            this.setFondo=function(fondoAux){
                this.fondo=fondoAux;
            };
            this.setFondoSrc=function(fondoSrcAux){
                this.fondo.src=fondoSrcAux;
            };
        };
```

### Thanks

Comment: probably because by the time you run `getFondo()` the image hasn't been retrieved yet, so there's no heigh data available. setting `src` is asynchronous - execution continues immediately, and the image will be loaded in the background while the rest of your script runs.

Comment: is your png located on the same path as the file containing this script?

Comment: Yes, it is located on the same path. Solved with this code. "imageAsync.onload = function () {
  console.log(this.height);
}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of the image takes some time to load in a `async fashion`

Let's take Google's Doodle as an example:

```
var imageAsync = new Image();
imageAsync.src = "https://www.google.com.br/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png?t=" + (+new Date);
console.log(imageAsync.height);

var imageSync = new Image();
imageSync.src = "https://www.google.com.br/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png?t=" + (+new Date);
imageSync.onload = function () {
  console.log(this.height);
}
```

Returns 0 and 92.

Comment: Thanks. Thank you helped me! Solved

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem @Moses91

Answer (score 0):

You will need to listen to the `load` event.

This should work:

```
function getHeight() {
    alert("Altura " + fondoJuego.fondo.height );
    return true;
}

var FondoJuego = function() {

    this.fondo = new Image();

    this.fondo.addEventListener("load", function(){
        getHeight();
    });

    this.getFondo=function(){
        return this.fondo;
    };

    this.getFondoSrc=function(){
        return this.fondo.src;
    };

    this.setFondo=function(fondoAux){
        this.fondo=fondoAux;
    };

    this.setFondoSrc=function(fondoSrcAux){
        this.fondo.src=fondoSrcAux;
    };
};

var fondoJuego = new FondoJuego();

fondoJuego.setFondoSrc("tituloNV.jpg");
```

check this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dm7dqajf/